# Rules are made to be broken vs He is the man to rely on

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, infinitives, to-infinitive

**He is the man *to* rely on**

and

**Rules are made *to be* broken**

What's the difference between the **to** and **to be** in these two sentences?

Can I say both sentences the other way around?

*He is the man to be relied on*

and

*Rules are made to break?*

But from what I've searched on Google, there's no such thing as *Rules are made to break?*

I think it's because **Rules are made to be broken** applies to everyone and **He is the man to rely on** applies to only the speaker(s) and their listener(s). Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence the verb is **to rely [on]**. It is used in its infinitive form, meaning the "to" is part of the infinitive, because the main verb in the sentence is the verb "to be"—conjugated in this example as "he is."

In the second sentence the verb is **to break**, again used in its infinitive form but this time *in the passive voice*. Again the main verb is "to be"—conjugated as "rules are"—and the infinitive form is used for the second verb in the sentence. The active infinitive is **to break** and the passive infinitive is **to be broken**, which is formed by taking the infinitive of the verb "to be" and appending the past participle of the verb "to break." This is the standard way to construct a passive infinitive in English, although the past participle of "to break" is itself irregular.

---

As for switching around the active and passive in your examples:

- (?) *He is the man to be relied on.*
  This is not a natural phrasing. I would prefer *He is **a** man to be relied **upon***. (In fact I would prefer **a** rather than **the** in the original active-voice sentence.) But the meaning is essentially the same as the original, which is not always the case when changing between the active and the passive voice!
- *Rules are made to break.*
  This is a grammatically acceptable sentence but—as is more often true—does *not* have the same meaning as the original. "Made to be broken" means that the rules have to be broken *by some person* doing something that is contrary to the rules. "Made to break" doesn't even make sense; rules must be broken *by* some person, and in fact it doesn't really work to say that even a physical object is "made to break." Things don't *break* on their own; they might *fade* or *crumble* but even then you expect some agent to bring about that change, even if the agent is a natural phenomenon like sunlight.

Comment: Your explanation is quite useful. So better to say **This is a perfect tree to be leaned against** than **This is a perfect tree to lean against**. And as for the first sentence, (by the way I quoted that from Wikipedia: English relative clauses and the original article is **the** not **a** so I asked if it was only known by the speaker and their listener) I can choose either the active voice structure or the passive voice one, e.g *She is the woman to beat* or *She is the woman to be beaten*. Although I still think the latter conveys the availability of the beating of the woman.

Comment: @Clansky A native speaker would say "This is a perfect tree to lean against" when they are actually leaning on the tree or considering leaning on it themselves, or "This is a perfect tree for leaning on" if they are speaking about the tree in general. "to be leaned against" is an awkward construct.

Comment: @Clansky unfortunately with this type of "referential" or "recommending" sentence the normal rules of when to use "the" or "a" might not apply. Note especially the use of the pronoun "he" which means the referent must be known already; but you can say *He's **a** man you can trust* (one of several such men you can trust) or *He's **the** man you want* (there is no other possible substitute). Plus more idiomatic phrases like *He's your man!* Perhaps this deserves a new question.

Answer (score 0):

He is the man to rely on. The phrasal verb here is: rely on, implying on someone.

The verb (above) is in active voice.

- I rely on him or on that man. He **is the man to be relied on** [by us]. **The sentence can be made passive like that.**
- Rules **are made to be broken** [by whomever]. is already in the passive form or voice.

A passive is made by using the verb be followed by the past participle. The past participle here is broken. Break, broke, **broken.**